# obtain a specific value from a RDD according to another RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I want to map a RDD by lookup another RDD by this code:

```
val product = numOfT.map{case((a,b),c)=>
 val h = keyValueRecords.lookup(b).take(1).mkString.toInt
 (a,(h*c))
}
```

a,b are Strings and c is a Integer. keyValueRecords is like this: RDD[(string,string)]-
i got type missmatch error: how can I fix it ?
what is my mistake ?

This is a sample of data:

```
userId,movieId,rating,timestamp
1,16,4.0,1217897793
1,24,1.5,1217895807
1,32,4.0,1217896246
2,3,2.0,859046959
3,7,3.0,8414840873
```

I'm triying by this code:

```
val lines = sc.textFile("ratings.txt").map(s => {
  val substrings = s.split(",")
  (substrings(0), (substrings(1),substrings(1)))
})

val shoppingList = lines.groupByKey()

val coOccurence = shoppingList.flatMap{case(k,v) => 
  val arry1 = v.toArray
  val arry2 = v.toArray

val pairs = for (pair1 <- arry1; pair2 <- arry2 ) yield ((pair1,pair2),1)
 pairs.iterator
   }          

 val numOfT = coOccurence.reduceByKey((a,b)=>(a+b)) // (((item,rate),(item,rate)),coccurence)

  // produce recommend for an especial user 


  val keyValueRecords = sc.textFile("ratings.txt").map(s => {
  val substrings = s.split(",")
  (substrings(0), (substrings(1),substrings(2)))
}).filter{case(k,v)=> k=="1"}.groupByKey().flatMap{case(k,v) => 
  val arry1 = v.toArray
  val arry2 = v.toArray

val pairs = for (pair1 <- arry1; pair2 <- arry2 ) yield ((pair1,pair2),1)
 pairs.iterator
   }   
 val numOfTForaUser = keyValueRecords.reduceByKey((a,b)=>(a+b))

 val joined = numOfT.join(numOfTForaUser).map{case(k,v)=>(k._1._1,(k._2._2.toFloat*v._1.toFloat))}.collect.foreach(println)
```

The Last RDD won't produced. Is it wrong ?

Comment: You can't nest RDDs like this. You need to join the two RDDs (presumably on the `b` value) to make another RDD, then map that

Comment: I'm trying to join two RDD. their structure are same as each other. and i'm trying on a sample of data (its not very big) - i dont have error but it dosent show the result by command collect.foreach(println)

Comment: Can you update the question with the code you're trying? (and some small sample data)?

Comment: I'm guessing this is because you in line 3 create key-value pairs from `(substrings(0), (substrings(1),substrings(1)))` - note the index of substrings - whereas you further down create key-value pairs from `(substrings(0), (substrings(1),substrings(2)))`. So your rdd is empty which is why nothing is printed.

Comment: @Glennie Helles Sindholt Yes, this was because of what you say :), thank you